# 503 All backends failed or unhealthy

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, google-cloud-platform, npm-install

I'm trying to deploy the updates to the node.js code for Google cloud, but got an error

```
503 All backends failed or unhealthy: @google-cloud/pubsub@https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud/pubsub/-/pubsub-0.13.0.tgz
```

Logs

```
4421 http fetch GET 503 https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud/bigtable/-/bigtable-0.10.1.tgz 104057ms attempt #3
4422 verbose unlock done using /Users/alexsanderjob/.npm/_locks/staging-13d056e7ffbe8bc7.lock for /Users/alexsanderjob/Desktop/Backend/Backend/node_modules/.staging
4423 verbose stack Error: 503 All backends failed or unhealthy: @google-cloud/pubsub@https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud/pubsub/-/pubsub-0.13.0.tgz
4423 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:41:19)
4423 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
4423 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
4423 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
4423 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
4423 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
4423 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
4423 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
4423 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
4423 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:649:20)
4423 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:622:5)
4423 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:594:5)
4424 verbose cwd /Users/alexsanderjob/Desktop/Backend/Backend
4425 verbose Darwin 16.6.0
4426 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "--save" "google-cloud"
4427 verbose node v6.9.5
4428 verbose npm  v5.0.4
4429 error code E503
4430 error 503 All backends failed or unhealthy: @google-cloud/pubsub@https://registry.npmjs.org/@google-cloud/pubsub/-/pubsub-0.13.0.tgz
4431 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I start the process as follows

```
 MacBook-Pro:Backend alex$ npm install --save google-cloud
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think It can be a temporary issue, when `https://registry.npmjs.org` was down or something. So it doesn't depend on you, just service|resource aren't working